# How to optimize flutter build size for multiple platforms

Tags: flutter, compiler-optimization, multiplatform

I'm new to flutter (1 month) and currently in an internship.

My company has been working on an Android application, and now decided to create a new github repository to port the app to PC. I believe that by applying the right design patterns, both PC and Android app can be maintained in a single codebase, but one of my coworker's concern is that, the resulting build size of the app is going to be big because everything (both PC and Android source code files) will be bundled.

So, I'm curious about how "flutter build" works, whether they exclude unused import files of our codebase from the resulting bundle app, whether there's any build options I can use to achieve that,...

I have googled and read about Flutter Architecture, but they don't mention anything. I'll appreciate it if anyone could provide me any docs link that describes this process.